Drop down menu Autofill
Hey I need help in this
example:

I first solved the proplem of showing the correct cities based on the what was selected in the first drop menu by using this formulas in data validation: (coutry and city are named ranges for countries and cities)
=IF($E$3="US",OFFSET(city, 0, 0, 2, 1),city)
But the problem is that drop down values are not autofilled for example If I pick international and click on Paris, paris will stay there even if I changed to E3 to us.
What I want to achive here to make drop down values dynamic change values after changing value of the controlling drop down or at least make the first value as default I whish you got me. Thanks
=SI($E$3="US",OFFSET(city, 0, 0, 2, 1),city)

AFAIK you cannot modify another cell content with data validation.

Thanks for your comment. I tried to use if formula on the cell but it's gone after selecting a value on the drop menu. I think the only way to do this is by vba: set values conditinally and update cell with the first value on drop menu that s filtered

I solved this by adding conditional formating - highlighting the city cell if is not a city in the selected country. By using the fomula =XLOOKUP(E3&E4,A2:A5&B2:B5,B2:B5,FALSE,0,1)=FALSE
